# How to get the value without the mask characters in PrimeNg?

Tags: angular, typescript, mask, primeng

I am using primeNG UI library for our angular project. I am used primeng mask to format the values.

```
        <p-inputMask type="text" name="IBANAccount"
                                     #IBANAccount="ngModel"
                                     mask="aa99 9999 9999 9999"
                                     (onBlur)="OnIBANAccountChange()"
                        [ngModel]="CurrentPaymentOutRequest?.IBANAccount"  (ngModelChange)="CurrentPaymentOutRequest.IBANAccount=UnMask($event)">
</p-inputMask>
```

In my Unmask method, I removed the mask values.

```
UnMask(val) {
    return val.replace(/\s/g, '');
}
```

I have a few questions.

*Why mask, binding the mask characters(ex:/,-,etc)?*

*Is any other way to handle this globally?, because in future if format change I should change it in all places*

Answer (score 5):

Set the `unmask` property (which is `false` by default) to `true` to get the raw value.

Example:

```
<p-inputMask mask="aa99 9999 9999 9999" unmask="true"></p-inputMask>
```

To set it globally, you could create a directive (don't forget to declare it in your module) with `p-inputMask` as selector, for example:

```
import {Directive, Host} from '@angular/core';
import {InputMask} from 'primeng/primeng';

@Directive({
  selector: 'p-inputMask'
})
export class InputMaskDefaultDirective {
  constructor(@Host() private inputMask: InputMask) {
    this.inputMask.unmask = true;
  }
}
```